# Score node doesn't show up, objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, sprite

I have two scores,one for each team, one right side shows up and works, second doesn't. here what I got:
**PalyerNode.m**

```
- (id)initOnRightSideCom
{
self = [super init];
if (self) {

    self.name = @"rightPlayer";
    ComputerPaddleNode *comPlayer = [[ComputerPaddleNode alloc] initWithName:@"rightPaddle"];
    [self addChild:comPlayer];

    ScoreNode *score = [[ScoreNode alloc] initWithName:@"rightScore"];
    [self addChild:score];
}
return self;
}
- (void)positionOnRightSideCom
{

SKNode *paddle = [self childNodeWithName:@"rightPaddle"];
paddle.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(self.parent.frame) -50, CGRectGetMidY(self.parent.frame));

SKNode *score = [self childNodeWithName:@"rightScore"];
score.position = CGPointMake((CGRectGetMidX(self.parent.frame) + 50), self.parent.frame.size.height - 70);
}
```

**GameScene.m**

```
-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
 PlayerNode *comPlayer = [[PlayerNode alloc] initOnRightSideCom];
[self addChild:comPlayer];
comPlayer = (PlayerNode *) [self childNodeWithName:@"rightPlayer"];
[comPlayer positionOnRightSideCom];
```

because I use this same code on left side, i know this will work, but, I don't know why it doesn't show up

Comment: Check zPositioning to see if everything is in right (z) order. Also, double check if nodes are really on screen or you have things off-screen (print their positions). Or if you want better help, make an example which can reproduce the issue. With the code you've posted it is not possible to reproduce the problem that easily.

Comment: Like @Whirlwind has stated, your right side is not on screen.  If going by defaults, what is happening is your scene is probably something like 1024x768, and the default code is setting the fill to aspect fill. This means the score should show up because you are calling the middleX but the paddle is not because you are calling maxX, and thanks to aspect fill, your maxX is beyond the view